# Curiculum Vitae template based on the pdf-file below?

Tags: cv

I am wondering if you know any Latex-template that is similar to the following PDF's structure:
http://cep.lse.ac.uk/people/cv/Farzad_Saidi-Varnosafaderani.pdf

Currently I am editing my CV in Microsoft Word, but I think there are ways that are more clever.

Kind Regards!

Comment: This was one in Word.

Comment: Another source of cv templates (without any judgement of quality) => http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae

Comment: Does any of the replies answer your question?

Comment: Hi Ecofritze. I like the CV-templates posted recently. However, I don't mind considering more templates.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in some standard LaTeX classes for writing a CV take a look on [this](https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cv#.VrYV0_DGKrU) and [this](https://www.ctan.org/topic/cv) page. But none of them look's exactly as your current one. If that's most important to you, you should consider writing your own class or write custom commands for a `scrartcl`:

```
\newcommand{\mytopicfont}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\topic}[1]{\par\noindent\underline{\mytopicfont\MakeUppercase{#1}\hspave*{\fill}}\\}
```

I'm sorry for not testing them -- I'm writing on my iPad. You should then use them like `\topic{education}` inside the `document` body.

Edit (2016-03-14): You should definitely have a look at [this](https://de.sharelatex.com/blog/2011/03/27/how-to-write-a-latex-class-file-and-design-your-own-cv.html) page!

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same, but I think it's the direction you want:
[ShareLaTeX Professional CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fb8c0933621a613683ecac)

If you accept somehow different solutions take a look at [ShareLaTeX' CVs and Resumes](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume)